# Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1916 (note 1 of 2)

Tags: identificación-de-término

For the year 1916 in my great-grandfathers Civil Guard records there are two entries.

Here is the first note:

[image]

I have guessed at some of the words here! Transcription so far:

> Según estación de xxx fecha 8 de mayo fue destinado a pueston xxx al
> puesto de xxx.
>
> El Comandante Mayor

I am not sure if it reads towards the end **puesto** or **punto**. I guess it depends on the actual *location* which looks like *Badxxx*. I don't think it is *Barcelona*.

---

#### Translation

Based on the answer I have the following translation:

> According to the transfer list dated 8 May, he was assigned to the
> Badolatosa post.
>
> The Major Commander

---

### Related Questions

- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1916 (note 2 of 2)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39485/28260)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestions

> Según relación de traslados fecha 8 de mayo fue destinado a prestar
> sus servicios al puesto de [Badolatosa](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Badolatosa)
>
> El Comandante Mayor

As you can see following the link, **Badolatosa** is a small town near Corcoya.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question with the initial translation. This link might be interesting. http://www.badolatosa.es/es/actualidad/noticias/EL-CUARTEL-DE-LA-GUARDIA-CIVIL-DE-BADOLATOSA-DISPONE-DE-4-NUEVOS-EFECTIVOS It mentioned both Badolatosa and Corcoya in connection with the Guardia Civil.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Yes, it seems that in this case the post is still open. Corcoya is part of the municipality of Badolatosa. In Spanish is called a pedanía. I don't know the exact term in English. WordReference suggests "district".