# Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1916 (note 2 of 2)

Tags: identificación-de-término

For the year 1916 in my great-grandfathers Civil Guard records there are two entries.

Here is the second note:
[image]
Transcribed text so far:

> Según xxx expedida por el Señor Coronel Subinspector del Tercio, de le
> fuexxx el xxx de en galon de destinación que le corresponde por llevon
> 12 años en la carrera de las armas y en el xxx de xxx finió el año.
>
> El Comandante Mayor

12 years? Now this sounds interesting. Thanks for reviewing the transcription for me.

---

#### Translation

Based on the answer provided I have the following translation:

> According to a certificate issued by the Colonel Sub-Inspector of the
> Tercio [Third], he is granted the use of a gallon of distinction that
> corresponds to him for 12 years in the career of arms and in the post
> of Badolatosa he finished the year.
>
> The Major Commander

We know that my great-grandfather did his national service between 1902 - 1904 in Osuna and Cadiz. So this note has to apply to the period 1904 - 1916 (thus matching the stated 12 years).

What exactly is this *gallon of distinction*? Something he would wear?

---

### Related Questions

- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1916 (note 1 of 2)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39483/28260)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but it seems that this _galloon_ was something he would wear in the arm. Check out [this picture](https://www.todocoleccion.net/militaria-fotografia/jx-273-fotografia-sargento-guardia-civil-tres-galones-antiguedad-epoca-alfonsina~x25904132) of a civil guard wearing 3 of these galloons. According to [this post in a forum](http://mundomilitaria.es/foro/index.php?topic=3540.435), the first galloon was awarded after 12 years of service, the second after 17 years and the last one after 21 years.

Comment: @gparis That is very interesting. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: @gparis Maybe considering incorporating some of that information about the galloons into your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some suggestions:

> Según **cédula** expedida por el Señor Coronel Subinspector del
> Tercio, **se** le **concede** el **uso** de **un** galón de
> **distinción** que le corresponde por **llevar** 12 años en la carrera de las armas y en el **puesto** de **Badolatosa** finió el año.
>
> El Comandante Mayor

After a quick research, I think this galloon was probably something he would wear in the arm, as it appears in [this picture](https://www.todocoleccion.net/militaria-fotografia/jx-273-fotografia-sargento-guardia-civil-tres-galones-antiguedad-epoca-alfonsina%7Ex25904132) of a civil guard sergeant wearing 3 of these galloons. According to this [other post in a forum](http://mundomilitaria.es/foro/index.php?topic=3540.435), the first galloon was awarded after 12 years of service, the second after 17 years and the last one after 21 years.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have updated the question with the proposed translation and some other queries that I have.

Comment: I've updated the answer with the information about the galloons.

Comment: Found another indirect reference for us: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galloon

Comment: It is a pity that in his notes so far we did not come across another reference to these galloons. Certainly not in the 1920 - 1922 notes period.